# using account create in metamask with Nethereum

Tags: nethereum, c#

Can I use an account created in metamask using nethereum? I tried this:

```csharp
var abi = @"";
var addressContract = "";
var myAddress = "xxxxx";
var password = "password";
var managedAccount = new ManagedAccount(myAddress, password);

var web3ManagedAccount = new Web3(managedAccount);
var contract = web3ManagedAccount.Eth.GetContract(abi, addressContract);

var method= contract.GetFunction("method");

SendTransactionAndWaitForReceiptAsync(from: myAddress, new HexBigInteger(3000), value: null, null, abcBytes, newAddress);
```

but return an error that say:The method personal_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available

**Update**

I had a big mistake, I needed to pass the private key and not the password, thanks for your help

```csharp
var abi = @"";
var addressContract = "0xA0XXXXX";
var myPriveteKey= "myKey";
var managedAccount = new ManagedAccount(myPriveteKey);
...
```

Comment: you need to check version of web3.

Comment: Are you suggesting a transaction or are you actually performing the transaction on behalf of the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is generally causing because of two problems :
>
> 1. mismatch version of your web3
> 2. forgot to unlock the account the send transactions.
>
> So, try to change the version of web3 and try again or you need to
>   unlock account that you are going to use for send transactions.